# How to locate a link using page object model after mouse over

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, pom

When I hover over login text there are list of links, i need to select Infostore using Page Object model approach. I am new to Selenium could any one help. I have the outer HTML for you:

```
<div class="desktop-login">
     LOGIN
     <ul class="no-bullet list-nav-child sub-menu-lv">
         <li class="nav-child-item">
             <a href="https://infostore.saiglobal.com/">Infostore</a> 
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes like this,

**Your POM class something look like this:-**

```
 public class Homepage{
  WebDriver driver;
  public Homepage(WebDriver driver) {
        //super();
        this.driver = driver;
    }
        private static final By loginLink= By.linkText("LOGIN");
        private static final By infostoreLink= By.linkText("Infostore");

      public void clickInfostoreLink() { 
          WebElement element= driver.findElement(loginLink);
          Actions action= new Actions(driver);
          action.moveToElement(element);
          action.build().perform();
          driver.findElement(infostoreLink).click();
    }
    }
```

**Your Test class like this:-**

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {
@Test()
  public void infostoreTest() {
Homepage add= new Homepage(driver);
add.clickInfostoreLink();

//Whatever you want to test according to your test case

}
}
```

and **BaseTest class look like this:-**

```
public class BaseTest { 
public static WebDriver driver; 

@BeforeTest
  public void LaunchApplication() 
  {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Intel\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseURL);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

 @AfterTest
  public void closeApplication()
  {
      driver.quit();
  }
}
```

hope this will help you to get some idea about POM.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a question of breaking the action from high levels of abstraction to the lower ones:

Test:

```
homePage.selectLoginOption("Infostore");
```

Home Page:

```
NextPageAfterClickOnTheOption selectLoginOption(String option) {
   desktopLogin.open();
   return desktopLogin.selectOption(option); // you can do .open().selectOption(option)
}
```

DesktopLogin:

```
DesktopLogin open() {
  loginListButton.click(); // or do the hovering
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(loginList)
  );
  return this;
}

NextPageAfterClickOnTheOption selectOption(String option) {
   loginList.getOptionNamed(option).click();
   return new NextPageAfterClickOnTheOption();
}
```

LoginList

```
WebElement getOptionNamed(String optionName) {
   return options.stream()   // convert list to stream
            .filter(option -> optionName.equals(option.getText())) // Just take the options named as the argument we passed
            .findFirst().get() // I am just interested in the first result
}
```